# Php contact form keeps going to spam and has an html attachement

Tags: php, html

I experiencing a problem with a php contact form that I normal use on our products sites.

```
    <?php

    $to = "martin@puritech.co.za";
    $subject = "Reverse Osmosis";

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $number = $_POST['tel'];
    $mail = $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From: $name \r\n";
    $headers .= "Email: $email \r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n";

    $message = "<html><body style='font-family: Arial;'>";
    $message .= "<h1>Hello Guys! You have a request from ".$name."</h1>";
    $message .= "<p>".$mail."</p>";
    $message .= "<p><span style='font-weight:bold;'>From:</span> ".$name."</p>";
    $message .= "<span style='font-weight:bold;'>Email:</span> ".$email."</p>";
    $message .= "<span style='font-weight:bold;'>Contact Number:</span> ".$number."</p>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";

    $send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if ($send==true) {
        header('Location: ../index.html');
        exit;
    }else {?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('Please check your details and resend. Thank you.');
            window.location = '../index.html';
        </script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

When I click on the send button, the mail goes straight to spam and has an html doc attachment.

How do I fix this? really draining me and its starting to annoy me.

Comment: There are so many reasons this could be happening. Sendgrid has a top10 list of items to help reduce the chance of this happening at https://sendgrid.com/blog/10-tips-to-keep-email-out-of-the-spam-folder/ Point 10 may be the most relevant to you. My general suggestion is to use a service that does this as their "job".

Comment: You can also use some library like SwiftMailer or phpMailer to resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies. What I need to know is why is the mail sending the message body as an html ducoment attachment